# flow_from directory found 0 images

Tags: keras, deep-learning

```
nb_classes = 5
lbls = list(map(str, range(nb_classes)))
batch_size = 32
img_size = 150
nb_epochs = 10
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=df_train,
    directory='E:\\all\\DR\\train_images',
    x_col="id_code",
    y_col="diagnosis",
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle=True,
    class_mode="categorical",
    classes=lbls,
    target_size=(img_size,img_size),
    subset='training')

validation_set = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=df_train,
    directory='E:\\all\\DR\\train_images',
    x_col="id_code",
    y_col="diagnosis",
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle=True,
    class_mode="categorical",
    classes=lbls,
    target_size=(img_size,img_size),
    subset='validation'
)

Found 0 validated image filenames belonging to 5 classes.
Found 0 validated image filenames belonging to 5 classes.
```

I tried to keep images in separate folder and then tried to access but same problem occurred again many solutions tried nothing is working on it

Comment: Does the files exist in directory: `E:\\all\\DR\\train_images` and do you have permission to access the path? Can check with doing this: `import os; os.listdir('E:\\all\\DR\\train_images')` and checking whether you can see the file names listed? Also try what happens if you add additional `\\` to the end of path

Comment: I tried os.listdir() it's showing all the images and by adding \\ at the end still getting the same issue

Comment: Does the id_code column's values match with the filenames in the folder?

Comment: YES id_code matches as well before image generator everything is running fine but whenever i try to perform data augmentation technique it show 0 images